# help with mysql select query

Tags: mysql

what I'm trying to do:

from these tables

```
---------------------------------
name      date      state
---------------------------------
ali      jan 12    started

ali      jan 12    drop out

masa     jan 12    registered

masa     jan 12    started

sami     jan 12    started
```

I want the results to be

```
---------------------------------
name      date      state
---------------------------------
masa     jan 12     started

sami     jan 12     started
```

So basically what i want is to have all the started users without the ones who dropped out 
so the filtering should be based on the state
thanks

Comment: well on what category would you want to filter out data

Comment: You should show what you have tried already to show what you are having trouble with

Comment: i already tried something like :
select * from log where log.state = started and log.state !=drop out
but it didn't work the way i want it because it would show "ali" as started even though he is not anymore (drop out)
so what i want is something to show people who started and still starting (didn't drop out)

and oh the drop out date is always after the start date but i omit the day for simplicy as i can simply "group by" and add "having" the date between the 2 dates

Comment: thanks experminetX for the edit it's so much clearer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something along the following lines is what you need...

```
SELECT NAME,
       DATE,
       STATE
   FROM MYTAB
   WHERE STATE = 'Started' AND
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                         FROM MYTAB MYTAB2
                         WHERE MYTAB2.NAME  = MYTAB.NAME AND
                               MYTAB2.STATE = 'Drop Out');
```

That should get everyone who started and didn't drop out.

Comment: thank you i think this would solve it
although i need to try it first,
will it work in MS Access ?
sorry for my laziness

Comment: @Ali, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: it worked but it's taking forever to show the results...:( why is that?

Comment: @Ali, if you are using MySQL, you could try `EXPLAIN ...`, and post the results; otherwise I'd guess you need an index on the NAME and STATE columns, but without the explain results, that is a guess. How large is your table?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCTROW Basic.ApplicationNumber
FROM Service INNER JOIN (Basic INNER JOIN Log ON Basic.[b_id] = Log.[b_fid]) ON Service.[service_id] = Log.[s_fid]
WHERE (((Format$([ServiceDate],'mmmm yyyy'))="January 2011") AND ((Service.ServiceName)="english") AND ((Log.state)=1) AND ((Exists (

Comment: SELECT DISTINCTROW Basic.ApplicationNumber as ap
FROM Service INNER JOIN (Basic INNER JOIN Log ON Basic.[b_id] = Log.[b_fid]) ON Service.[service_id] = Log.[s_fid]
where  (log.state=3) and Format$(ServiceDate,'mmmm yyyy')="January 2011" AND Service.ServiceName="english"
))=False));

Comment: it is Access sql but it shows nothing,
i know i'm missing something like "where basic1.app=basic2.app" but i can't seem to be able to alias the table when i add inner join
thanks

Comment: @Ali, perhaps that would be better posted up as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Those two rows in your result example are not the only started people on that date.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = 'started';
```

Would return 3 rows:

```
---------------------------------
name      date      state
---------------------------------

ali      jan 12     started

masa     jan 12     started

sami     jan 12     started
```

To get the two rows in your example you need:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('sami', 'mesa');
```

Update, added this example

You could limit if you only wanted two rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = 'started' LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply
but i want my results filtered based on the state not the names

Comment: Sorry your question was unclear, this is what you need:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE state != 'drop out' GROUP BY name;`

This will only show one row per name, and no one who has dropped out.

Comment: No it wouldn't! `GROUP` will only show people (once) who have not dropped out. Try it!

Comment: yes but what if someone registered and didn't start, the query only exclude the drop out
am i right?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, date, state FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING state = 'started';
```

I believe this would eliminate people who dropped out eventually because the `GROUP BY` would put the people with the same name into the same group, and then eliminate them once they drop out with the `HAVING` statement.

Comment: thanks for your reply
that would show Ali who started but then droped out while what i needed only people who started and didn't drop out

Comment: SELECT Basic.ApplicationNumber,log.state
FROM Service INNER JOIN (Basic INNER JOIN Log ON Basic.b_id = Log.b_fid) ON Service.service_id = Log.s_fid
WHERE (Service.ServiceName="english" AND Format$(log.ServiceDate,'mmmm yyyy')="January 2011")
GROUP BY Basic.ApplicationNumber,log.state having log.state=1

it didn't work it shows all the started and it does not exclude the drop outs

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from table where state != 'dropped out'
```

Comment: -1 that would include the registered row too. (should your sql say `drop out`)

Comment: exactly :)
i don't want to show the registered i only need the started who didn't drop out